# Direction of spin state from time evolution operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

In a oscillating magnetic field of the form $$\mathbf{B} = B_0 \cos(\omega t)\mathbf{e}_z$$ with Hamiltonian $H = -\gamma \mathbf{B} \cdot \mathbf{S}$, I found that the unitary time evolution operator is $$U(t) = e^{\frac{i\gamma B_0 \sigma_z}{2\omega} \sin(\omega t)}.$$ Now this means that if the initial spin is an eigenstate of $S_x$ with eigenvalue $\hbar/2$ (so spin up), then the state at a time $t$ is $$|\psi, t\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(e^{\frac{i\gamma B_0 \sigma_z}{2\omega} \sin(\omega t)} |+\rangle + e^{\frac{i\gamma B_0 \sigma_z}{2\omega} \sin(\omega t)} |-\rangle).$$ I know that the spin up state in a general direction is $$|\mathbf{n}, +\rangle = \cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)|+\rangle + \sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)e^{i\phi}|-\rangle$$ where $\theta$ is the angle from the positive $z$-axis and $\phi$ is the angle from the positive $x$-axis. Now to find $\theta$ and $\phi$, I can compare my spin state and this spin state but I seem to need to take the cosine of a complex number. How do I do this or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: All your work aside, the trig functions of complex arguments are given by their hyperbolic counterparts (ex $\cosh{z} = \cos{iz}$).